# How to assign window tint color to view background color or lable text color dynamically- iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, tintcolor

In the storyboard, we have the option to change Global tint color as shown below:
[image]

Is there any way to assign same tint color to Lable text color using storyboard? as I don't want to create the new reference of the label to change color only.

And when I will change global tint color then all text field text color should be changed.

Comment: Is there any way to assign same tint color to Label text color using storyboard? I think you can't.In my opinion, you should create a subclass for `UILabel` to change text color when global tint color changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to apply label color globally from storyboard. 
But you can create Custom Label Class in which you can set default color for label. Finally assign that class in identity inspector of every label you have added in storyboard by selecting label.

```
    class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        //you can set your properties
        //e.g
        self.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }

}
```

Comment: there are some errors in your code that's why I have updated your answer.

Comment: Yeah it was just a sudo. Thanks